# Laravel Eloquent model with counter

Tags: laravel, count, eloquent, has-many, relationships

I'm trying to count all the files within a category, and I have these two relationships:

`public function files() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\File', 'category_id','category_id');
    }
    public function fileCount() {
        return $this->files()->selectRaw("category_id, count(*) AS count")
        ->groupBy('category_id');
    }`

This gives me a collection of items, where the `count` attribute could be accessed like this:

    `$my_category = Category::where("category_id", category_id)->with('fileCount')->get();
    $file_counter = $my_category->first()->fileCount->first()->count;`

Is it possible to directly attach the `count` attribute to the `$my_category` variable? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method:

```
$my_category = Category::where("category_id", category_id)
                       ->withCount(['files' => function($q) {
                           $q->groupBy('category_id');
                       })
                       ->get();
```

This will put `files_count` attribute into results.

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will place a {relation}_count column on your resulting models